# The easiest way to build and deploy an iPhone application that just points to my web app

Tags: iphone

I just want an icon on my users iPhone that takes them to my web applications. This is more of a bookmark than an actual application :)

Is there a quick and easy way to do this without having to mess with Objective C?

Also can I avoid the app store for my deployment?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah you can add an icon to your markup like this:

```
<head>
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="iphone.png"/>
</head>
```

Users can go to your web app in Safari, bookmark, and choose to save to the home screen.

Answer (score 1):

You could teach them how to do this themselves:

1. Go to your site using Safari on the iPhone
2. Click on the + sign at the bottom of the screen
3. Click on the "Add to Home Screen" button

This will give them an icon on their iPhone that looks like any other application, but is simply a shortcut to your site in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

shure you can.
safari has a built in bookmarking option, where your website is stored as an icon on springboard.

you can customize this icon by adding

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/customIcon.png"/>
```

to your website header.

you can also do things link hiding the url bar, with special meta tags in your website source code.

check google for that, there are tons of informations